# C# Serialising/deserialising Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, serialization, listviewitem

I'm trying to serialise data from a ListView as well as then deserialising it and also consequently fill the ListView with the saved data.

```
 public List<ListViewItem> SaveListView(ListView LV)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<ListViewItem> lSavedLV = new List<ListViewItem>();

        for (int i = 0; (i <= animalList.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            lSavedLV.Add(LV.Items[i]);
        }

        return lSavedLV;
    }
```

Is that a plausible solution for the saving part? Is that the way to go, if I plan to fill the ListView with such serialised data? Is this then a matching loading method:

```
 public ListView LoadListView(List<ListViewItem> L)
        {
            ListView lv = new ListView();

            for (int i = 0; (i <= (L.Count - 1)); i++)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                lvi = ((ListViewItem)(L[i]));
                lv.Items.Add(lvi);
            }

            return lv;
        }
```

My mind really wanders, I've been trying a few different things but it seems that the there is something wrong with the loading/filling of the ListView. It's detail view. Ideas, tips?

Comment: ListViewItem is serializable... List<T> is Serializable ... so basically you can serialize that List ... but your code doesn't show any serialization ... and in code block 2 you are creating a ListVieItem (lvi=new ListViewItem()), just to throw it away in the next statement ... I don't really get your question ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Are you sure `ListViewItem` is serializable? I tried `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListViewItem));` but I got a type reflection exception...

Comment: @programmer93 ... well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx says it has the SerializableAttribute

Comment: Why serializable the ListView and not bind it to a collection(that you can serialize)?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Well, sorry if my question was a bit confusing. What I'm trying to do is to serialise data from a ListView. And what I'm uncertain of is the way to when saving the data - should that be done as a List<ListViewItem> and then if so, does the second block properly refill/load a new ListView?

Comment: @ValiD What do you mean by binding it to a collection? Isn't the List<ListViewItem> a proper container for the data?

Comment: you can do that, and i think I can provide an example ... but like @ValiD already asked, why do you try to save a view? save your data, and bind to that data ... or create views of it at runtime ... EDIT: ListViewItem is the problem ... if you have Animals in your list, then have a class Animal ... store objects of the Type Animal and no ListViewItems ... once you want to display your Objects, create a View from it or bind to your data ... if you want to store it, save your data .. not a view ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I might have expressed myself in a fussy way, but it is the data within the ListView and of course not the ListView per se. Of course, yes, I have class for the objects that are being stored, but where am I mistaken - aren't the objects being stored in the ListView by being added as a ListViewItem?

Answer (score 3):

Not trying to be patronizing here, but a ListView is presentation logic. A ListViewItem is presentation logic. You should not serialize those. What you should do is serialize your data, not its visual representation.

Why not have a class which contains the data to be visualized?

```
public class DataIWannaVisualize
{
    // ...
}
```

Make it serializable by giving it the appropriate attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataIWannaVisualize
```

And have a List of these data objects.

```
IList<DataIWannaVisualize> dataList = new List<DataIWannaVisualize>();
```

This list contains the data that you are about to make visible, on which you do your changes, and so on. And which, of course, can also easily be serialized or deserialized.

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open("data.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, dataList);
}
```

Now, your ListView. Fill it by having a handler on the Load event of your Form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataIWannaVisualize dataObject in dataList)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        // TODO: Fill the item with the desired data.
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And best of all, you won't have to worry about serializing UI logic classes.

Answer (score 0):

Callash already provided an sufficient answer but if you want to see a full example ...

It's not using a ListView, but a DataGridView ... but it will show you how to persist data and how to load it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataExample
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _Filename = "MyAnimals.xml";
        public List<Animal> myAnimals = new List<Animal>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void RegisterDog(String name)
        {
            myAnimals.Add(new Dog { Name = name });
        }
        public void RegisterCat(String name)
        {
            myAnimals.Add(new Cat { Name = name });
        }

        private DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 199);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 229);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 21);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "persist to file";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(151, 229);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "make dummy objects";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterDog("SomeDog");
            RegisterCat("SomeCat");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myAnimals;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(_Filename))
                {
                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Animal>), new Type[] { typeof(Dog), typeof(Cat) });
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myAnimals);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(_Filename))
                {
                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Animal>), new Type[] { typeof(Dog), typeof(Cat) });
                    myAnimals = (List<Animal>)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = myAnimals;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public abstract String Species { get; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Dog : Animal
    {

        public override string Species
        {
            get { return "Dog"; }
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Cat : Animal
    {

        public override string Species
        {
            get { return "Cat"; }
        }
    }

}
```

if it really has to be a ListView, you can use a loop like the one Callash has in his Form1_Load(...) to make new ListViewItems from your data once it has been deserialized ...